# Is it possible to show, $S_4$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$ using homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> **Question**: Prove that $S_4$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$?

**My attempt**: If $Q_8$ isomorphic to subgroup of $S_4$ then there exists a homomorphism from $f: S_4\rightarrow Q_8$ such that,

$\frac{S_4}{\ker f}≈Q_8$ (Am I correct?)

this implies $|\ker f|$ must be equal to $3$. But $S_4$ has no normal subgroup of order $3$ and so... statement follows...

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: No.  "Is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of" is certainly not "is a homomorphic image of".

Comment: @user10354138  sir "why" ?

Comment: $A$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $B$ means there is an injective homomorphism $A\to B$.  It doesn't say anything about homomorphisms $B\to A$.  For example, the cyclic group of order 3 is a subgroup of $S_3$, but there are no nontrivial homomorphisms $S_3\to C_3$.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Better that we revert to you the question. How would you prove your assumption?

Comment: @user10354138 thank you so much sir. For reply.

Comment: Your argument, if it were correct, would show $S_4$ has no 8-element subgroup at all. But it has several subgroups isomorphic to the dihedral group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quaternion group has six elements of order four, and they all have the same square. $S_4$ also has six elements of order four, the six four-cycles, but they don't all have the same square. So, $S_4$ can't have a subgroup isomorphic to the quaternion group.